# Prove that there exists a prime numbers $p$ such that $\min(S_{p}(a)+S_{p}(n-a),S_{p}(b)+S_{p}(n-b))\ge p-1+S_{p}(n)$

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$be an integer greater than $1$ and let $a,b$ be postive integers smaller than $n$, Prove that there exists a prime numbers $p$ such that
$$\min(S_{p}(a)+S_{p}(n-a),S_{p}(b)+S_{p}(n-b))\ge p-1+S_{p}(n)$$

Here $S_{p}(n)$ is the sum of the digits of n when written in base p,

For this problem ,I don't have any idea

Comment: Where did you get the $S_p$ notation from?

Comment: (Also you have 2 $*$s - to get upvotes, show your working)

Comment: What is the range of values of $n$ you have tested this for? I don't know if it helps in this particular case, but that's how I would begin my attack on this problem. Just to see how the land lies.

Comment: Also, is the minimum to be taken for all $a,b$ in the prescribed range, or just any pair of such numbers. It feels odd, that the minimum would taken from an arbitrary pair. Not impossible (it could be that the inequality is violated for at most a single choice of such an integer), but in that case it is IMHO a somewhat odd way of phrasing the claim?